# Playing mp3 files in Visual BASIC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to play audio files in Visual BASIC programs. It needs to add windows media player tool to play mp3 files. It adds two dll files with the application but I want to built a single executable file. I've already tried:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(path)
```

But it requires a .wav file which is very large in size. Is there any way to play mp3 files in a Visual BASIC program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing a .wav/.mp3 file at the start of a VB2010 windows form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244068/playing-a-wav-mp3-file-at-the-start-of-a-vb2010-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework doesn not support MP3 files natively (so far). Therefore you will have to reply on a third-party framework to help. And unless you get access to the source code of this framework, you will have the incorporate it using (most likely) DLLs and won't be able generate a single .exe file.

If you are willing to switch to C++, some like this could help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191/A-very-simple-MP-Player