# Playing mp3 file with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I followed the tutorial on NAudio's website on how to load and play an mp3 file, but even though I put the audio file in the right directory, whenever I run, the program crashes with "vshost32.exe has stopped working." Any ideas? I'm using Visual Studio 10.0 on Windows 7.

Here's the (exact) code that the tutorial gave me:

```
   namespace NAudioTest
   {
       class Program
    {
    static IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;
    static WaveStream mainOutputStream;
    static WaveChannel32 volumeStream;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
        mainOutputStream = CreateInputStream("Kalimba.mp3");
        waveOutDevice.Init(mainOutputStream);
        waveOutDevice.Play();
    }

    private static WaveStream CreateInputStream(string filename)
    {
        WaveChannel32 inputStream;
        if (filename.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(filename);
            inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
        }
        volumeStream = inputStream;
        return volumeStream;
    }

}
}
```

(sorry for the poor formatting)

Comment: What do you mean by crashes.. can you put break points and step thru the code and explain state which line the error is being thrown..?

Comment: How do the examples in naudio work out for you?

Comment: It looks like the error is just at the waveOutDevice.play() line, and the NAudioDemo.exe works, but it looks like NAudioDemo.cs has missing files in the project solution?

Comment: you need to show us the exception and stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, used this code to get the audio file to work:

[How to play a MP3 file using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488426/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-using-naudio?rq=1)

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         using (var rdr = new Mp3FileReader(filename))
         using (var waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
         {
              waveOut.Play();
              while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
              {
                  Thread.Sleep(100);
              }
         }
     }
  }
```

Is this better? Although I'm not really sure where WaveOutEvent goes. 
Thanks for all of your help!!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this technique with versions of NAudio newer than 1.3. Get rid of ms, wavStream and baStream - all are unnecessary.  Also, WaveOutEvent will be more reliable than using FunctionCallbacks.

Comment: Awesome, found another source using WaveOutEvent, much better. Thanks for creating this!

Comment: @m00nbeam360: Can you provide it (Link or code) for everyone?