# NAudio WaveBadFormat exception while trying to streaming mp3

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio

I am trying to play an mp3 from an internet source while streaming in the same time. I've writen the code below and it throws the exception `WaveBadFormat calling WaveOut` at the `player.Init()` line. How should I fix this?

```
string testLink = "http://users.skynet.be/fa046054/home/P22/track49.mp3";

req = WebRequest.Create(testLink) as HttpWebRequest;
resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
str = resp.GetResponseStream();

int readBytes = 0;
int totalBytes = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] mp3Buffer = new byte[45000];

IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;
BufferedWaveProvider provider = null;
WaveOut player = new WaveOut();
Mp3Frame frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(new ReadFullyStream(str));

while ((readBytes = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    totalBytes += readBytes;
    if (decompressor == null && totalBytes > 1024) 
    {
        Mp3WaveFormat format = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate,
                    frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2,
                    frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate);
        decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(format);

        provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
        int x = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, mp3Buffer, 0);
        provider.AddSamples(mp3Buffer, 0, x);
        player.Init(provider);
        player.Play();
        continue;
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
    if (decompressor == null)
        continue;
    int decNum = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, mp3Buffer, 0);
    provider.AddSamples(mp3Buffer, 0, decNum);

}
```

Comment: Might be similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488426/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-using-naudio), but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think the problem is same. Because in that code, the source is a file, in my project the source is an url source. I have tried to implement Mark Heath's streaming code in [here](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioDemo/Mp3StreamingDemo/MP3StreamingPanel.cs). But some problems was occured.

Answer (score 0):

the `WaveFormat` of your `BufferedWaveProvider` should be the PCM format you decompress the MP3 into, not an `Mp3WaveFormat`. Your `WaveOut` device can only play PCM.